# Add An If statement to a value using php

Tags: php

how do i add an if statement to a Php value, this is what i tried

```
&n = 1;
$number = if(10 < 1)
{
   $n = 0;
}
```

is there any way to fix this or something i didn't ad that made it not to work?
because it kept showing an error message that the code is not right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo and some syntax error.

```
&n = 1;
```

That should be:

```
$n = 1;
```

Also, you can't really assign the value of an `if` statement to your variable.

Try [simply using a ternary instead](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
$n = (10 < 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: not the greatest example because `$n = 10 < 1;` is way shorter

Comment: @DarkBee He's not trying to assign a boolean, he's trying to assign an actual `1` or `0`.  The point of the example is to show how a ternary works.

Comment: I know but due to the type juggling in PHP it does not matter really

Comment: @DarkBee It absolutely does matter.  There is a real difference between `1` and `true` and `0` and `false`.  Use the correct type for what you're doing, always.  Type coercion conveniences are not there for you to store data in a format that doesn't make sense.  It's there for easy comparison among others.

Comment: Only when you're actually testing for the type with `===`. [example](http://ideone.com/MPw2V3), anyway enough nagging :-)

Comment: @DarkBee It actually does matter. If the OP intends to increment the value later on, `true + 1` won't give the same result as `(1 + 1)`.

Comment: There you go: http://ideone.com/k9dF8T
Not behaving the same as if $val was 1. I should've said `true++` won't give the same value as `1++`.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, `if` is a statement, but the `=` operator expects an expression, so that is invalid syntax. If you want to assign something to `$number` when the condition is true, then you can use something like:

```
if (10 < 1)
{
    $number = ...;
    $n = 0;
}
```